# msqldbcompare failed because of special characters

Tags: mysql, xtradb, mysqldbcompare

I'm trying to compare master and slave using mysqldbcompare utility, but observed that it's getting failed and in compare result its not showing difference rows.so I manually compared tables and observed that there is some special character in master is making this difference in slave as '?'.
Please let me know how can I avoid this issue.

below is the sample record from master and slave.

```
Master:

mysql> select description  from mp_prod.devices where id=22672\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
description: Amanda iPad - 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

slave :

mysql> select description  from mp_prod.devices where id=22672\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
description: Amanda iPad - ?
```

Comment: Is this cause one db is using UTF-8 and the other is not?

Comment: Yes but when i compared the charset variables and table structures all looks same between master and slave.

Comment: did anyone came across this issue.please let me know.I'm facing this comparison issue daily.let me know a solution for this.